# Hand over global variables to methods in python?

Tags: python, coding-style

This is more a question about good programming style. I usually work with Java, and now I do some working with Python. In Python, there is no need to hand over global variables if you only want to read from them. On the other hand, I think the Java syntax is more helpful in his regard. You have to hand over required variables, and so you can see what variables are used by what method, which I am sure is helpful for somebody who is reading your code.

Now do you hand over variables in Python although you could already access them because they're global? What is the good 'pythonic' way?

Thanks,

ZerO

```
def foo(a):
    a = 2
foo(1)
```

1 is 'handed over' to method foo().

Comment: Imo the good way is to not use global

Comment: That IS true. But when i write a script with a couple of methods, and some code accessing the methods afterwards, variables that are declared outside of a method are global, aren't they? At least for reading I think. Sry if I'm wrong, but I am really new to Python.

Comment: No, in python variables are global if you declare them with the `global` keyword

Comment: How about packing up related stuff in a class and make your current global variables into class instance variables, which coulc be initialised in `__init__` ?

Comment: Ok, this is strange. Can you explain to me why I can still read them from inside any method body?

Comment: @GodMan: I was told not to declare any classes :/

Comment: Because the method is in the same scope. I know what you mean when you say global, but python has a special keyword for `global` variables, I didn't want to make you think a variable declared outside of a method is the same as declaring a variable with `global` keyword

Comment: Oh, OK! Yep I already came across the "global:" keyword. Now that we made this clear, what do you think is good programming style in my case? Should I hand them over to the method, or not? ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'handing over variables' could you maybe  explain again or perhaps give a code example?

Comment: I edited my question with a small example ;)
sry i have no idea what's the right word in english for this

Comment: Oh yes, this is the preferred way. Imagine you have 5 methods that all do something to a list. If you define the list 'global' you will have to refer that exact list in each method. If you for some reason want to change the list name you now have to edit all 5 methods. However if you pass in the list through a parameter you only have to edit the method calls and the method code can remain untouched. This makes your code more modular, and most of all it makes your code testable

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted to know!

Comment: Great let me post that as answer so we can close this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this

```
def foo(a):
    a = 2
foo(1)
```

is preferred over this

```
a = 1
def foo():
    a = 2
foo()
```

Imagine you have 3 methods that all do something to a list.

```
a_list_name = []

def a()
    a_list_name.something

def b()
    a_list_name.something

def c()
    a_list_name.something

a()
b()
c()
```

If you define the list 'global' you will have to refer that exact list in each method. If you for some reason want to change the list name you now have to edit all 3 methods.

However if you pass in the list through a parameter you only have to edit the method calls and the method code can remain untouched. Like this

```
def a(l)
    l.something

def b(l)
    l.something

def c(l)
    l.something

my_list = []
a(my_list)
b(my_list)
c(my_list)
```

This makes your code more modular, and most of all it makes your code (methods) *testable* because they don't depend on some variable that is defined somewhere else